# Sort by index in java

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting

I have a task in the university where I need to sort student by their IDs using *Sort by index* after they were sorted by their group number using *Bubble sort* . My sorting method does not sort anything aat all. 
I have created a Student class with necessary data, Sortings class with Student type array. And I have static method for this type of sorting in main class, where I create an instance of Sortings and call my static methods for sorting.

```
public static void index_Sort(Student[]st, int []a)
{
    int temp;
    for(int k = 0; k < a.length; k++)
    {
        for(int i = k+1; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            if(st[a[k]].get_ID() > st[a[i]].get_ID() )
            {
                temp = a[k];
                a[k] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main class

```
int index[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5}; 
    Student s_arr[] = new Student[6];
    s_arr[0] = st; //s_arr.add(st)
    s_arr[1] = st1;
    s_arr[2] = st2;
    s_arr[3] = st3;
    s_arr[4] = st4;
    s_arr[5] = st5;

    System.out.println("__________SORT BY INDEX __________");
    index_Sort(new_sort.st,index);
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in debugger, watching the variable values change? This is the way to understand what's happening

Comment: You are not reordering your Students array (`Student[] st`), you are reordering your int array (`int []a`) .

Comment: Your methods currently sorts by id in descending order (id[k] > id[i] with k > i), sure that is what you want? Besides that as Berger already noted you're sorting `index` so maybe you're just looking at the wrong array.

Comment: thank you very much, I didn`t notice

Answer (score 1):

You are not sorting the Student array object.

You are sorting the int array 'a'.

```
public static void index_Sort(Student[]st)
{
Student temp;
int len = st.length;
for(int k = 0; k < len -1 ; k++)
{
    for(int i = k+1; i < len ; i++)
    {
        if(st[k].get_ID() > st[i].get_ID() )
        {
            temp = st[k];
            st[k] = st[i];
            st[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
}
```

main class:

```
Student s_arr[] = new Student[6];
s_arr[0] = st; //s_arr.add(st)
s_arr[1] = st1;
s_arr[2] = st2;
s_arr[3] = st3;
s_arr[4] = st4;
s_arr[5] = st5;

System.out.println("__________SORT BY INDEX __________");
index_Sort(s_arr);
```